# Snake game in Python

Tags: python, game, snake-game

I am a biologist.  Some time ago, I wanted to learn to program, and since I am fascinated by the 4th dimension and I was fascinated by the rotatation of hypercubes and hypersphere, so I decided to understand it better, and thanks to the work of Steve Hollasch, I understood that humans cannot "see" the 4th dimension, only project it in the 3 dimensional world.

Anyway, after finding the function to project the 4th dimension, I wanted to do something interactive with it, something where one can learn where and how the object moves in a 4 dimensional space. So I came up with the idea of a simple game: Snake.

[snake4d](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IUnqm8j4BE)

Can you please comment on the code here?

```
__author__ = "Mauro Pellanda"
__credits__ = ["Mauro Pellanda"]
__license__ = "GNU"
__version__ = "1.1.0"
__maintainer__ = "Mauro Pellanda"
__email__ = "pmauro@ethz.ch"
__status__ = "Devlopment"


''' In this file is contained the snake definition'''

def get_random_color():
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % (random.randrange(0,255), random.randrange(0,255), random.randrange(0,255))

from vec import *
import time


class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head_pos = V4(0,0,0,0) #position of the head
        self.head_dir ="UP" #direction of the head
        self.p_list = [] #store the polygon of the snake
        self.score = 0 #score
        self.score2 = 0 #number of cube taken
        self.time = 0. #boh
        self.color = [0, 255, 0] #color
        self.color_var = "up" #Variable to circulary change color


    def create_cube(self,point):
        '''This function return the polygon coordinates in a
        determined postion defined by point'''
        #calculate coordinates
        v = V4(.4,.4,.4,.4)
        higher = sum4(point,v)
        lower = sub4(point,v)
        c = cube4d(lower,higher)
        #calculate the color
        if self.color_var == "up":          
            self.color[0] += 20
            if self.color[0] > 255-21:
                self.color_var = "down"
        elif self.color_var == "down":
            self.color[0] -= 20
            if self.color[0] < 21:
                self.color_var = "up"           
        color_tuple = (self.color[0],self.color[1],self.color[2])
        c.color = "#%02x%02x%02x" % color_tuple
        #add the tag for the canvas (not used in this version)
        c.tag = "snake"
        return c

    def initialize_snake(self):
        '''it initialize the snake at the original position with 4 cubes'''
        self.__init__()
        size = 4
        for x in range(size+1):
            point = V4(0,-(size-x),0,0)
            self.p_list.append(self.create_cube(point))

    def move(self,dir):
        '''check if is a valid move in that direction, the snake cannot go
        in opposite direction'''
        no_move = False
        if dir == "UP" and self.head_dir != "DOWN":
            dir_v = V4(0,1,0,0)
        elif dir == "DOWN" and self.head_dir != "UP":
            dir_v = V4(0,-1,0,0)
        elif dir == "LEFT" and self.head_dir != "RIGHT":
            dir_v = V4(-1,0,0,0)
        elif dir == "RIGHT" and self.head_dir != "LEFT":
            dir_v = V4(1,0,0,0)
        elif dir == "FW" and self.head_dir != "RW":
            dir_v = V4(0,0,1,0)
        elif dir == "RW" and self.head_dir != "FW":
            dir_v = V4(0,0,-1,0)
        elif dir == "IN" and self.head_dir != "OUT":
            dir_v = V4(0,0,0,-1)
        elif dir == "OUT" and self.head_dir != "IN":
            dir_v = V4(0,0,0,1)
        else:
            no_move = True

        if not no_move:
            #move the snake, and append a new polygon in the new position,
            #take off the polygon from the tail, the snake is stored in the
            #list like this: [tail,->,head]
            self.head_pos = sum4(self.head_pos, dir_v)
            self.head_dir = dir
            self.p_list.pop(0)
            self.p_list.append(self.create_cube(self.head_pos))
```

1. Are the comments useful to understand what I did?
2. Do you have any suggestions about the programming style and/or the algorithms?

[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?b8ocioxx80wnnxq) is the download of the complete source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
__author__ = "Mauro Pellanda"
__credits__ = ["Mauro Pellanda"]
__license__ = "GNU"
__version__ = "1.1.0"
__maintainer__ = "Mauro Pellanda"
__email__ = "pmauro@ethz.ch"
__status__ = "Devlopment"


''' In this file is contained the snake definition'''
```

For this to be recognized as a docstring I think it needs to be the first thing in a file.

```
def get_random_color():
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % (random.randrange(0,255), random.randrange(0,255), random.randrange(0,255))

from vec import *
import time
```

imports are typically placed before function definitions

```
class Snake:
```

If you are working python 2.x, I recommend you make your classes inherit from object. That way they are new style classes.

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.head_pos = V4(0,0,0,0) #position of the head
        self.head_dir ="UP" #direction of the head
```

Using a string for something like this is a little odd. I suggest a boolean value or an integer.

```
        self.p_list = [] #store the polygon of the snake
        self.score = 0 #score
        self.score2 = 0 #number of cube taken
        self.time = 0. #boh
        self.color = [0, 255, 0] #color
```

I'd make color a tuple. Lists are for storing, well lists, not related items like colors. I know you do this so you can modify it. But I'd create new tuples everytime I changed the color.

```
        self.color_var = "up" #Variable to circulary change color
```

Agains strings are odd unless its actually text. It'll take slightly longer to compare strings then say ints or bools.

```
    def create_cube(self,point):
        '''This function return the polygon coordinates in a
        determined postion defined by point'''
```

Typically, the first ''' and final ''' are placed on a line by themselves
for multiline docstrings

```
        #calculate coordinates
        v = V4(.4,.4,.4,.4)
        higher = sum4(point,v)
        lower = sub4(point,v)
        c = cube4d(lower,higher)
        #calculate the color
        if self.color_var == "up":          
            self.color[0] += 20
            if self.color[0] > 255-21:
                self.color_var = "down"
        elif self.color_var == "down":
            self.color[0] -= 20
            if self.color[0] < 21:
                self.color_var = "up"           
        color_tuple = (self.color[0],self.color[1],self.color[2])
```

You can just do `color_tuple = tuple(self.color)`

```
        c.color = "#%02x%02x%02x" % color_tuple
```

You've duplicated the tuple to string logic here and in the random color function. I suggest refactoring so they share it.

```
        #add the tag for the canvas (not used in this version)
        c.tag = "snake"
        return c

    def initialize_snake(self):
        '''it initialize the snake at the original position with 4 cubes'''
        self.__init__()
```

Don't ever do that. `__init__` is called when the object is built. You shouldn't call it later. Python will let you, but nobody expects you to do it and you are liable to confuse people.

```
        size = 4
        for x in range(size+1):
            point = V4(0,-(size-x),0,0)
            self.p_list.append(self.create_cube(point))

    def move(self,dir):
        '''check if is a valid move in that direction, the snake cannot go
        in opposite direction'''
        no_move = False
        if dir == "UP" and self.head_dir != "DOWN":
            dir_v = V4(0,1,0,0)
        elif dir == "DOWN" and self.head_dir != "UP":
            dir_v = V4(0,-1,0,0)
        elif dir == "LEFT" and self.head_dir != "RIGHT":
            dir_v = V4(-1,0,0,0)
        elif dir == "RIGHT" and self.head_dir != "LEFT":
            dir_v = V4(1,0,0,0)
        elif dir == "FW" and self.head_dir != "RW":
            dir_v = V4(0,0,1,0)
        elif dir == "RW" and self.head_dir != "FW":
            dir_v = V4(0,0,-1,0)
        elif dir == "IN" and self.head_dir != "OUT":
            dir_v = V4(0,0,0,-1)
        elif dir == "OUT" and self.head_dir != "IN":
            dir_v = V4(0,0,0,1)
        else:
            no_move = True
```

Chains of elifs are a sign to look for a better solution. For example, you could have a dictionary mapping directionts to opposites and vectors. Then you'd just have to fetch from the dictionary.

```
        if not no_move:
```

Double negative, consider inverting the logic on no_move so it becomes moved.

```
            #move the snake, and append a new polygon in the new position,
            #take off the polygon from the tail, the snake is stored in the
            #list like this: [tail,->,head]
            self.head_pos = sum4(self.head_pos, dir_v)
            self.head_dir = dir
            self.p_list.pop(0)
            self.p_list.append(self.create_cube(self.head_pos))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments!! A specific question about the elif chain, can I define something like this dic_opp_dir = {"UP":"DOWN", ecc} then call def catch_dir(dir_x): for dir in dic: if dir_x == dic[x]: move = false ?

Comment: And there are enum in python? in C++ I defined the directions as enum. And is better then a string, because giving an int decrease the readability of the code...

Comment: @Pella86, why are you wanting to put a loop in that example? Just check if dir_x == dic_opp_dir[head_x]. Python doesn't have enum, but I'd add global constants UP = 0 and DOWN = 1 and use those.

Comment: I didn't know such things can be done with a dictionary... I almost never use them (even though I know they are really useful). And about the global constat I thought it too, but maybe there was a better way. Thank you!

Comment: You wrote to never call self.__init__() I usually don't do this, but I need it to reset all varibles, there is a nicer way to do it instead of copying the init funtion in the initialize_snake?

Comment: @Pella86, probably all those assignments should be moved into initialize_snake. The constructor should either call initialize_snake itself, or set all the variables to None, or both.